# A pointless riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, english

*Please explain all lines.*

> I may seem small and useless
> Several letters but less than one
> In fact I am not here, not at all
> But I am near; up above.
>
> Good James made me famous
> So when he humbles himself I appear.
> I often carry three crosses
> For without them I am a contorted falsehood.
>
> Remove one stroke and I become what I am.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are

> the dot above a lowercase I or J.

I may seem small and useless

> the point above the letter I is indeed small, and you'd recognise the letter even without the dot

Several letters but less than one

> lowercase J also has this part of a letter in it

In fact I am not here, not at all
But I am near; up above.

> not a single lowercase I or J in the riddle itself, a couple in the intro text though.

Good James made me famous

> In Jesus's "sermon on the mount", the King James Bible translation famously uses the tiny dot to make a point: "For verily I say unto you, Till heaven and earth pass, one jot or one tittle shall in no wise pass from the law, till all be fulfilled"

So when he humbles himself I appear.

> This might also refer to "James" (or "Jesus") beginning with the uppercase letter J, which would have a dot if brought to lowercase.

I often carry three crosses
For without them I am a contorted falsehood.

> The dot is often called a "tittle", which has three lowercase t's (crosses). If those are removed, what remains is "ile", an anagram of "lie"

Remove one stroke and I become what I am.

> in cursive handwriting, removing a stroke from "tittle" gives you "little".

Comment: You got "jot"!  i'd like to add that lowercase "i" is the least non-zero non-infinitesimal constant.  It doesn't even exist.

Comment: Should point out rot13(gur fvtavsvpnapr bs gur jbeq "cbvagyrff" va gur gvgyr.  (Nyfb n zvffrq bccbeghavgl gb znxr gur gvggyr/gvgyr pbzcnevfba urer.))

Comment: This is amazing.  For the last clue, I had interpreted it differently - if you remove one stroke (the lower case i, or j), then it becomes what it is - just a dot.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you are:

> the number zero.

Pointless riddle:

> zero has no points (it's round)

I may seem small and useless

> zero is as small as it gets until you go negative.

Several letters but less than one

> zero has four letters, but 0<1

In fact I am not here, not at all

> there are no zeros in this riddle.

But I am near; up above.

> there are lots of the letter "o"s above in this riddle, which is very near to a zero.

Good James made me famous, So when he humbles himself I appear.

> I don't quite have this one, but Zero is a book by James Toogood.  Or, it may be a reference to James the Greater.

I often carry three crosses

> a peace sign is a zero (or circle) with three slashes across it.  Also, a common Christian symbol is three crosses in a circle.

For without them I am a contorted falsehood.

> a cricle with two slashes across it is a common symbol for "no" or "wrong" or "error" or any number of negative/false responses.

Remove one stroke and I become what I am.

> remove one of the two slahses and you get a slahsed zero which is just another way of writing a zero.

Comment: Yep I intentionally made 0 work for many but not all lines as a false trail, alas!

Comment: You had me at “pointless”.

Answer (score 4):

You are a

> tittle  (the dot over the i or j for one definition)

I may seem small and useless

> Certainly small and sometimes carelessly left off, so is it useless?

Several letters but less than one

> Used for i, j (several letters) but less than a whole letter

In fact I am not here, not at all

> You are not.  All of your "i"s are capitalized

But I am near; up above.

> In the title above, you are in the i in pointless and riddle.

Good James made me famous
So when he humbles himself I appear.

> Used in the King James Bible at Matthew 5:18: "For verily I say unto you, Till heaven and earth pass, one jot or one tittle shall in no wise pass from the law, till all be fulfilled"

I often carry three crosses

> The word tittle has 3 t's or crosses

For without them I am a contorted falsehood

> a lie (anagram of letters in tittle without t's)

Remove one stroke and I become what I am.

> tittle become little, which it is